# DataTables sAjaxSource Json higlight search data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, datatables

I am trying to implement search highlight on data table ( JSON data is coming and filling up the table from serverside through "sAjaxSource"), Please see the below code for details.

search is working by default, BUT highlight is not working at all.

**I alerted data of  searchTxt+=$('#search_input').val();       alert("txt" + searchTxt);
and alert is displaying search input box text.
Alert for " alert(""+ aData[j]); " displaying "undefined rather than column data and highlight is not working.**

Could anyone shed some light on this ?

Thank you,
Sri

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var oTable = jQuery('#example').dataTable({
 "sDom": '<"#table_header"<"#inner_table_header"<"filtertx">fCT<"filterbtn">>>tipl',
  "sAjaxSource": ajaxURL,
 "bDeferRender": true,
 "bProcessing" :  true,
 "bJQueryUI": true,  
 "sScrollY": 500,
 "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']],
 "aoColumns": [
  { "mData": "name" },
  { "mData": "flag" }
 ],
 "oSearch": {"sSearch": "", 
    "bSmart": true,
    "bRegex": false},
"sPaginationType": "paginate",
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
    $(nRow).addClass('clickable');  
    $(nRow).attr('onClick', "editPopup(" + aData['conditionId'] + ")");
},
"fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {
   $(expandWrapper);
 }
 });

   $("#example_filter label").attr("for", "search_input");
     $("#example_filter input").attr({
         "id": "search_input",
         "placeholder" : 'search'
    }); 
    oTable.fnSearchHighlighting();
  });

jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnSearchHighlighting = function(oSettings) {

        oSettings.oPreviousSearch.oSearchCaches = {};
        oSettings.oApi._fnCallbackReg( oSettings, 'aoRowCallback', function( nRow, aData,              iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                        var searchStrings = [];
                        var oApi = this.oApi;
                        var cache = oSettings.oPreviousSearch.oSearchCaches;
                    // Global search string
                    // If there is a global search string, add it to the search string array
                    if (oSettings.oPreviousSearch.sSearch) {
                        searchStrings.push(oSettings.oPreviousSearch.sSearch);
                    }
                    // Individual column search option object
        // If there are individual column search strings, add them to the search string array

    searchTxt=$('#filter_input input[type="text"]').val();
    searchTxt+=$('#search_input').val();

    alert("txt" + searchTxt);
    if ((oSettings.aoPreSearchCols) && (oSettings.aoPreSearchCols.length > 0)) {
        for (var i in oSettings.aoPreSearchCols) {
            if (oSettings.aoPreSearchCols[i].sSearch) {
                searchStrings.push(searchTxt);
            }
        }
    }
    // Create the regex built from one or more search string and cache as necessary
    if (searchStrings.length > 0) {
        var sSregex = searchStrings.join("|");
        if (!cache[sSregex]) {
            // This regex will avoid in HTML matches
            cache[sSregex] = new RegExp("("+escapeRegExpSpecialChars(sSregex)+")(?!([^<]+)?>)", 'i');
        }
        var regex = cache[sSregex];
    }
    // Loop through the rows/fields for matches
    jQuery('td', nRow).each( function(i) {

    // Take into account that ColVis may be in use
    var j = oApi._fnVisibleToColumnIndex( oSettings,i);
    // Only try to highlight if the cell is not empty or null

    alert(""+ aData[j]);

    if (aData[j]) {
    // If there is a search string try to match
    if ((typeof sSregex !== 'undefined') && (sSregex)) {
        alert("here");
        this.innerHTML = aData[j].replace( regex, function(matched) {
        return "<span class='filterMatches'>"+matched+"</span>";
        });
    }
    // Otherwise reset to a clean string
    else {
        this.innerHTML = aData[j];
    }
    }
    });
    return nRow;
    }, 'row-highlight');
    return this;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Wherever the search functionality is and if you are using mData to populate json data, use mData information to retrieve the column data and highlight ( DO  NOT use indexes to retrieve column data for search and highlight)

**var colProp = oSettings.aoColumns[i].mData;**

```
    jQuery('td', nRow).each( function(i) {
                    /* Take into account that ColVis may be in use

                        var j = oApi._fnVisibleToColumnIndex( oSettings,i);

                    Only try to highlight if the cell is not empty or null
                     */
                    var colProp = oSettings.aoColumns[i].mData;

                if (aData[colProp] !== undefined && aData[colProp] !== null && aData[colProp] !== "") {
                        // If there is a search string try to match
                        if ((typeof sSregex !== 'undefined') && (sSregex)) {
                            var mapObj = {
                                            '&#0174;' : "\u00AE",
                                            '&#0153;' : "\u2122",
                                            '&#034;'  : "\u201C",
                                            '&nbsp;'  : " "
                                        };
                                        aData[colProp] = aData[colProp].replace(/(&#0174;)|(&#0153;)|(&#034;)|(&nbsp;)/gi, function(matched){
                                            return mapObj[matched];
                                        }); 
                            this.innerHTML = aData[colProp].replace( regex, function(matched) {
                                return "<span class='filterMatches'>"+matched+"</span>";
                            });
                        }

                        else {
                            this.innerHTML = aData[colProp];
                        }
                    }
                });
                return nRow;
            }, 'row-highlight');
            return this;
```